# Angular2 Test Data Without CORS

Tags: apache, angular, npm, cors

I am writing a project with an Angular2 frontend and a REST WebAPI backend using php.

I have been running/debugging the frontend using `npm's` lite server (aka `npm start`). Until now, I have been using the `in-memory-web-api` to serve data, but I am ready to start consuming real data from the backend.

In production, both frontend and backend would be served from the same Apache server, but in development I have been using `npm` to run Angular2 and a separate Apache server to run the API.

My problem is that `npm` runs on `localhost:3000` and Apache on `localhost:80`. This creates cross origin security issues and the only way I can have my Angular2 app get data is to enable CORS on my REST API. I don't want to enable CORS on the backend if I can avoid it because I am worried that it may somehow make it's way into production.

So far, `npm's` server has been really nice because it compiles my .ts files automatically and will refresh the browser whenever it detects a change to the files. I would really rather not have to move my Angular2 development into Apache unless there is a way to keep these nice features.

Is there any way to keep these two things separate without having to enable CORS?

If not, is there a way I can merge the two while keeping npm's nice features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your development application server to proxy requests to the development REST server. Then make same origin requests.

Alternatively, use `.htaccess` to turn CORS headers on but add it to `.gitignore` (or your version control system's equivalent) to ensure it stays out of production.

Alternatively, if your REST server has a configuration system. Use that to turn on CORS in development (and again, ensure that the config file is kept out of version control).